# Построение формы html

Tags: php, html, css

Сделал форму ввода логина и пароля

```
print <<<HEREDOC
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='' method='POST' style='text-align:center'>

<p'>Логин<br />
<input type='text' name='login'>
</p>

<p>Пароль<br />
<input type='password' name='password'>
</p>

<p><input type='submit' name='button' value='Сохранить' style='width:223px; background:#5D80F9; color:white; padding: 7px'></p></form></div></div>
    HEREDOC;
```

Пикча формы: 
[image: nGrC9.png]

Как мне сделать, что бы надписи "логин" и "пароль" были левее, а не в центре, т.е. так: 
[image: 4rf4J.png]

Answer (score 2):

Правильнее будет в данном случае оборачивать не в параграф, а в `label`:

```
<label>Пароль<br />
<input type='password' name='password'>
</label>
```

и в форме изменить заданный стиль с `center` на `left`:

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='' method='POST' style='text-align:left'>
```

Либо добавить стили `label`:

```html
  <form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='' method='POST' style='text-align:center'>
  <label style='text-align:left; display: inline-block;'>Пароль<br />
    <input type='password' name='password'>
  </label>
</form>
```

Если все же с параграфом, то:

```html
  <form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='' method='POST' style='text-align:center'>
  <p style='text-align:left; display: inline-block;'>Пароль<br />
    <input type='password' name='password'>
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так:

```html
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='' method='POST' style='margin: auto; width: 200px'>

<div>Логин</div>
<input type='text' name='login' style='width:100%'>



<div style="text-align: left;  margin-top: 15px;">Пароль</div>
<input type='password' name='password' style='width:100%'>


<input type='submit' name='button' value='Сохранить' style='width:100%; margin-top: 15px; background:#5D80F9; color:white; padding: 7px'></form>
```

Но это далеко не лучший вариант. Лучше вам почитать какую нибудь статью про позиционирование ([например](https://webref.ru/layout/learn-html-css/positioning-content)). И заново переделать всю форму.

Answer (score 0):

Может float:left для обоих элементов прописать? Тем более что в стиле у Вас написано `style='text-align:center'`

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать например так:

```html
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='' method='POST' style='text-align:center'>
 
<p><span style="padding-right: 125px;">Логин</span><br />
<input type='text' name='login'>
</p>

<p><span style="padding-right: 115px;">Пароль</span><br />
<input type='password' name='password'>
</p>

<p><input type='submit' name='button' value='Сохранить' style='width:223px; background:#5D80F9; color:white; padding: 7px'></p></form>
```

Пример на [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Legionary/je2g7mzj/)